# How to join two table to get day sale

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join two table with some condition

Table 1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payment` (
  `paymentcode` int(6)  NOT NULL,
  `date` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `customer` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `store` varchar(200) NOT NULL
 )


  ('2', '20190120', '10050','C1','A'),
  ('2', '20190120', '10050','c2','A'),
  ('6', '20190120', '9050','c3','A'),
  ('4', '20190120', '9045','c4','B'),
  ('6', '20190121', '10050','c5','B'),
  ('2', '20190121', '20050','c6','A');
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `code` int(6)  NOT NULL,
  `name` int(3) NOT NULL,
  )


  ( 'C1','Customer1'),
  ( 'c2','Customer2'),
  ( 'c3','Customer3'),
  ( 'c4','Customer4'),
  ( 'c5','Customer5'),
  ( 'c6','Customer6');
```

```
select a.date,a.Paymentcode,a.store,b.Amount as document_total
from 
(select date ,Paymentcode,store,sum(amount) from payment
group by date ,Paymentcode,store
) a
join
(select date ,store, sum(amount)as Amount from Payment
group by date ,store) b
 on a.date = b.date and a.store = b.store
```

From above query I can fetch below value:

```
date     paymentcode  Amount           documet_total
20190120     2         20100               29150
20190120     4          9045                9045
20190120     6         18095               29150
20190121     4         20050               20050
20190121     2         10050               10050
```

This was the query I was trying. Now I want to JOIN customer table to get customer code if Paymentcode='2' else need to take store value

My expected out is below:

```
date     paymentcode  Amount customer_type  document_total
20190120     2         10050     C1           29150
20190120     2         10050     C2           29150
20190120     4          9045      B            9045
20190120     6         18095      A           29150
20190121     4         20050      B           20050
20190121     2         10050     C6           10050
```

Where I need to calculate amount based on date,store,customer_type and Paymentcode, customer_type should customercode it paymentcode='2' else store code, document_total is based on date,store.

Please advice me how to join these table and get the output

Comment: if you are newbie in sql server i highly recommend you to use wizard instead of running query to join two table .

Comment: I am assuming Customer in your payment table is actually the customer code? i.e the FK of Customer? Also looking at your data structures, you really need to read up on normalisation, keys and entities and what sort of data should make up these records.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? T-SQL doesn't use backticks (`\` `) to delimit identify; it uses brackets (`[]`). `int` does not support a length/precision value in SQL Server, and `unsigned` is also not a property of the datatype. SQL Server only supports signed numerical datatypes (with the exception of `tinyint`,  which is unsigned and only permits the values `0`-`255`).

Comment: Agreed, this does not look like SQL Server. Is it MySQL?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS is not SQL Server Syntax

Comment: I have removed the `sql-server` tag; as it is clearly incorrect. @Angel please edit your question and add the tag for the RDBMS you are actually using. It is incredibly important that we know the correct RDBMS in order to help you.

Comment: Thank you all.... Will check and update my question